# GHCi breaking the running application

Tags: haskell, ghci

I tried to run the sample tcp server application in http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Simple_Servers this address in my GHCi for Windows. When i run 'main' function it works and client can connect. But i want to break it and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> but it doesn't break. How can i break the running application in GHCi?

Comment: `Ctrl-C` usually *does* work for me.

Comment: Hitting `Ctrl-C` only sends the SIGINT signal to the main thread, it does not force the program to close.  Usually, the default behavior is to raise an exception in the main thread, but some libraries might override this behavior (though they shouldn't).  Additionally, GHCi definitely handles `Ctrl-C` differently (if you run GHCi in Cygwin, it prints a message warning to use a different script for proper `Ctrl-C` behavior).  Also, did you run `main` by simply typing `main<ENTER>`, or using the GHCi special command `:main`?

Comment: @bheklilr - both ways..

Comment: FYI- I just tried the sample server on an Ubuntu box, and `ctrl-c` worked in all cases (in/out of ghci, using `main`, `:main`, before after connection), so this is probably a Windows issue (ie- it probably isn't a lib hijacking `ctrl-c`)

Comment: Yes, it is also working on MacOSX..